# Can facts have sub-facts in JESS?

Tags: expert-system, jess

I have over 150 subjects and each subject has the following information which I want to put in my deffacts

```
> Subject: CS222 
> Pre-requisite: CS111
> Units: 4 
> Priority-lvl: 3
> Semester-offered: 2 
> Class: A
>        Schedule: 9:00am - 10:00am (Mon & Wed)
>        Slots Available: 30 
> Class: B
>        Schedule: 9:00am - 10:00am (Tue - Thurs)
>        Slots Available: 26 
> Class: C
>        Schedule: 12:00nn - 01:30pm (Mon - Wed)
>        Slots Available: 10
```

I know how to write deffacts but the problem here is that, I have two information for each Class (which clearly becomes subfact) and I dont know how to convert this information into deffacts.

I know I can make 4 deffacts with such information like below but I don't find the code efficient. Is there any other way to deffacts the information above?

```
(Deffacts subject
  (subject-information 
             (name CS222)
             (identifier 1)
             (pre-requisite CS111)
             (priority-lvl 3)
             (units 4)
             (semester-offered 2)))

(Deffacts Ident
   (ident-class
              (identifier 1)
              (class A)
              (schedule 0900-1000MW)
              (stud-avail 30)))

(Deffacts Ident
   (ident-class
              (identifier 1)
              (class B)
              (schedule 0900-1000TTH)
              (stud-avail 26)))

(Deffacts Ident
   (ident-class
              (identifier 1)
              (class C)
              (schedule 1200-0130MW)
              (stud-avail 10)))
```

Comment: Don't add tag "shell" to your questions.

Comment: I was adding it because I thought JESS was shell itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about memory consumption: 150 subjects and a few classes for each isn't anywhere near causing an OutOfMemory exception.

If you are worried about "efficiency" in terms of execution time, I cant say - it depends on the rules accessing these facts. Whether using two different deftemplates or squeezing it into a single one is better depends on what you want to do in the rules accessing the data. Usually it is best to avoid lists as properties and stick to the relational model, i.e., what you have.

The slot "identifier" doesn't appear in the raw data. I suppose you have introduced it for relating the class facts to the subject fact. It might be preferable to use the subject name instead.

Comment: I guess I'll just follow up with your way and remove the identifier instead so i wont need 4 deffacts. Thank you!

Comment: That I did *not* recommend - you'll still be left with 4 facts. And (at least not without knowing the rules for processing) I *do not,* repeat: do not, suggest to put it all into one big lump of data (by using multislots).

Comment: No ma'am, what I meant is I'll remove the identifier and use the subject name instead. That would still leave me with 3 facts.

Comment: I did not recommend to triplicate subject data either by storing that along with each class.